# Compare all columns in two rows in a SQL table without specifying each column

Tags: mysql

I have a series of tables that each have two identifiable rows and I need to compare each column to see what data is the same and what data is different.  Unfortunately, each table has different column titles and several of them have more than 10 columns so it's a little more work than I'm willing to do to rote-generate a SQL query for each table.  As might be evident by my lack of knowledge on how to really put this question into Stackoverflow, I operate in SQL scripts and can't really touch any proper programming language.

Can you help?

I'm working with MySQL8.

Here's an example (very small column count) that exemplifies what I'm trying to accomplish:

**my_data_table**:

| id | title | cost | description | config |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Smart Sounding Name | 1234.33 | Too expensive | { "color": "red", "shape": "round" } |
| 2 | Smart Sounding Name | 999.99 | Better price | { "color": "green", "shape": "round" } |
| 3 | Different Name | 1234.33 | Better price | { "color": "green", "shape": "round" } |

I need to run a report using the id. In this case, if I compare id = 1 and id = 2 to see what's different:

Ideal result:

| id | title | cost | description | config |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1, 2] | TRUE | [1234.33, 999.99] | ["too expensive", "Better price"] | [ {color: red}, {color: green}] |

Suitable result:

| id | title | cost | description | config |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |

I have tried things like

```
SELECT a.id = b.id AS id, 
       a.title = b.title AS title...
FROM my_data_table a 
JOIN my_data_table b 
ON a.id = 1 AND b.id = 2
```

but this is too manual for the 150-ish columns that I will ultimately have to key in.

Any help for this noob would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to get the column names in a table. Use this to generate dynamic SQL for the queries.